# Problems using cin.getline()

Tags: c++

im trying to use cin to get int input follow by a c-string. Currently i can take in the int input but for the c-string input would stop after the 8th input counting space. The input that im currently testing on is number-> space follow by letter-> space 5 times.

```
int main(){
    int* aNumber = new int;
    char temp[200];
    cin.getline(temp,255,' ');
    *aNumber = strtol(temp, NULL, 0);

    char *aString = new char[200];
    cin.getline(aString, 200);
}
```

Comment: Start from scratch. Use `std::getline`, `std::string`, `std::vector` and `std::stol` instead of all the pointer-infested, error-prone, old-fashioned C-like code you have come up with.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Is completely right! If however you don't do that, you should at least remember to do `delete aNumber` and `delete aString `

Comment: this is part of an assignment that i have. My program required to  take in a 1 line input that include an int and c-string each separate by spaces hence why i try to use cin.getline. As for all the pointer, i've just learned about pointer in class so im just trying to be more familiar with it.

Comment: This code segment should **not** allocate any object at all: there is no need for pointers or dynamically sized arrays. If you insist that you need to use pointer, you will have to make sure that all allocated memory with `new` is also released with `delete p` or `delete[] p` (depending on whether `p` is an array object or not). With respect to the input in your code, you are lying to the system: you claim that the memory pointed to be `temp` is 255 characters wide but it actually is only 200 characters wide. Also, you shall **always** verify if input was successful!

Comment: The problem is also not clear to me: there is no loop. There are only two inputs and no output. It seems you have cut down the problem from a bigger code (which is good) but you have cut down too much and, thus, it isn't possible to tell where things go wrong. You want to post a http://sscce.org probably consisting of a short piece of code and in this case its input.